# UPDATE (MySQL) not working combined with C# and ASP.NET

Tags: c#, jquery, mysql, asp.net, datagridview

So, I'm working with a datagridview and I'd like to select the value from the label that I Update but when I refresh the page it's just the value it used to be my code looks like this atm:

**IMPORTANT NOTE: I use a jquery that transforms the label to a textbox so I guess the problem is there. I overwrite the value of the label and do nothing with the changed text**

The foreach works for sure so don't look there. I'd be so glad that this is fixed thanks on advance!

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _controller = new Controller();

        //Variablen
        string afspraak ="";
        string uitleg ="";
        string id="";
        string id1 = "";

        //Values uit uit gridview halen halen
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            //Label1 = value van afspraak
            afspraak = ((Label)row.FindControl("Label1")).Text;

            //Label2 = value van uitleg
            uitleg = ((Label)row.FindControl("Label2")).Text;

            //Label3 = value van idcategorie
            id = ((Label)row.FindControl("Label3")).Text;

            //Label4 = value van idafspraken
            id1 = ((Label)row.FindControl("Label4")).Text;
        }

        //Methode om record te bewerken
        _controller.RecordUpdatenTblAfspraken(afspraak, uitleg, Convert.ToInt32(id), Convert.ToInt32(id1));

        //Pagina refreshen
        Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);

    }
```

**PersistCode:**

```
#region UpdateRecordsAfsprakenAdmin
    public void UpdateRecordsAfsprakenAdmin(string Afspraak, string Uitleg, int IDCategorieën, int IDAfspraken)
    {
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(_connectionstring);
        conn.Open();
        _sqlquery = "UPDATE knowledge_base.tblafspraken SET Afspraak = @afspraak, Uitleg = @uitleg, IDCategorieën=@id WHERE IDAfspraken=@id1";

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(_sqlquery, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@afspraak", Afspraak);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uitleg", Uitleg);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", IDCategorieën);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id1", IDAfspraken);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }

    #endregion
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function () {
    //Loop through all Labels with class 'editable'.
    $(".editable").each(function () {
        //Reference the Label.
        var label = $(this);

        //Add a TextBox next to the Label.
        label.after("<input type = 'text' style = 'display:none' />");

        //Reference the TextBox.
        var textbox = $(this).next();

        //Set the name attribute of the TextBox.
        var id = this.id.split('_')[this.id.split('_').length - 1];
        textbox[0].name = id.replace("lbl", "txt");

        //Assign the value of Label to TextBox.
        textbox.val(label.html());

        //When Label is clicked, hide Label and show TextBox.
        label.click(function () {
            $(this).hide();
            $(this).next().show();
        });

        //When focus is lost from TextBox, hide TextBox and show Label.
        textbox.focusout(function () {
            $(this).hide();
            $(this).prev().html($(this).val());
            $(this).prev().show();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You didn't include an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your post. We have no idea what your JavaScript is doing.

Comment: Sorry let me update that

Comment: Updated! Can you still have a look please would really appreciate it

Comment: 1st question when you say it's the old value when you update the page, does that mean your database is updated properly? did you execute a select query to check your database value?

Comment: Well I guess it does update since i think my code runs properly but he doesn't take the value with him from the textbox. Can I test this?

Comment: debug your javascript code and also check the values before "RecordUpdatenTblAfspraken" this function is called

Comment: I've tested it. It does use the old values even if it's changed. Is there any way I could get the id's from the textboxes individualy? So i could use their value?

Comment: I see this on inspect element: <input type="text" style="display: none;" name="7">

Comment: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Editable-Label-Convert-a-Label-to-TextBox-when-clicked-using-jQuery-in-ASPNet.aspx 

Found this online, there's a script to get the value but I don't understand how to get multiple ones

Comment: your _controller.RecordUpdatenTblAfspraken(afspraak, uitleg, Convert.ToInt32(id), Convert.ToInt32(id1)); should be within the foreach

Comment: also, what are label1, label2, label3, and label4? ID's?

Comment: Hi, okay i'll put it in there. Those labels are the ID's generated in my gridview by each label. Btw I'm able to make the value = null because I've added afspraak = Request.Form["txtName"] under the afspraak = ((Label)row.FindControl("Label1")).Text now I'm trying to figure out how to give that null value the value of the textbox again

Answer (score 0):

You need to make couple of modifications to the solution given [here](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Editable-Label-Convert-a-Label-to-TextBox-when-clicked-using-jQuery-in-ASPNet.aspx)

1. Since your label is generating id's of Label1, Label2, Label3

> ```
> var id = this.id.split('_')[this.id.split('_').length - 1];
>         textbox[0].name = id.replace("lbl", "txt");
> ```

this won't work 
you have to change textbox[0].name = id.replace("lbl", "txt"); to textbox[0].name = id.replace("Label", "txt");

2. You cannot have multiple elements with the same ID, you need to add logic to set a new ID for your labels
3. If you see the example, it has fetched the textbox and assigned its value to a label on the server side. You are not doing that, you need to fetch the textbox value not the label value

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I wanted to let you know that I replaced lbl with Label but when I inspect the textbox it's not replacing it, is this possible?